# Navigation Mesh, Chunks and Funnel Algorithm

Tags: path-finding, tilemap, navmesh

I am building a little RTS-like game as a side project and I am currently working on pathfinding. My approach to pathfinding is heavily inspired by things I saw in the Starcraft II map editor, which enables diagonal obstacles. My map consists of tiles that are subdivided into 4 triangles each and each triangle can be passable or not passable. I then build a navigation mesh by generating polygons (with holes) of the passable area and then triangulating them. See the following pictures for an example:

[image]

The colored areas are the triangulated polygons that make up the navigation mesh.

As an optimization I thought it would be a good idea to subdivide the map into chunks (i.e. 32x32 grid tiles) to allow for fast updates of the mesh (as soon as a triangle changes from passable/impassable I rebuild the whole chunk and update the navigation mesh accordingly). See the following picture for an example:

[image]

The red lines are the chunk borders (which is also why the color of the navigation mesh sometimes changes accross the borders).

The triangulation is a separate constrained delaunay triangulation for each chunk. For the chunk-wise updates to work I had to introduce constraints at the chunk borders for the triangles to line up. Up until now everything seemed to work fine. I then went to implement some pathfinding using A* on edge midpoints and path smoothing using the Simple Stupid Funnel algorithm (see "Efficient Triangulation-Based Pathfinding" by Demyen and Buro or [How does the Simple Stupid Funnel Algorithm work?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68302/how-does-the-simple-stupid-funnel-algorithm-work/68305)).

The problem is now that some triangles have their vertices at chunk borders that don't correspond to an obstacle. If such a triangle is part of a path found by A* the funnel algorithm uses it if it was a corner point of an obstacle and produces a wrong path. See the folowing picture for an example:

[image]

The red area is the passable area and has no obstacles inside. The green path is the path as it is found by e.g. A* and the blue path is the smoothed path using the funnel algorithm. Since there is an extra vertex in the navigation mesh introduced by the the chunk borders (where the 4 chunks meet) the funnel algorithm handles it the same as if it was the corner of an obstacle and thus the path is not a straight line but takes a detour around the corner. Ultimately I wanted to implement something along the lines of "Compromise-free Pathfinding on a Navigation Mesh" by Cui, Harabor and Grastien to find truly optimal paths in a navigation mesh. But all of those methods seem to assume that the navigation mesh contains no extra vertices except for the corners of obstacles (and the outer border of course).

I am looking for a solution for the problem of splitting the map into chunks for efficient updates of the navigation mesh while still being able to find optimal paths in an efficient manner (e.g. i don't want to do real line of sight checks instead of the funnel algorithm). My only other option it seems would be an algorithm for dynamic constrained delaunay triangulations and having a single triangulation for the whole map (since this would not introduce extra obstacles) which for one is pretty complicated and second (and more importantly) doesn't scale.

I know that this is a pretty open question. I hope it comes clear what I am looking for, since it was kind of difficult to phrase the problem :D
If anything needs clarification, please tell me :D

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the problem?